# my openmp code cannot work on a server?

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I have a simple openmp c++ code look like:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <string>

int main()
{

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    {
        printf(" %d", n);
    }
    printf(".\n");


}
```

It runs parallel on my Mac computer (after installing gcc48 from homebrew):

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:openmp_code me$ g++-4.8 tmp2.cpp -fopenmp
dhcp-18-189-47-44:openmp_code me$ ./a.out 
 2 7 4 9 5 8 6 0 3 1.
```

However, when I do the same on our computer sever (linux based), I can't reproduce parallelization:

```
[me@my_cluster trial_openmp]$ g++ tmp2.cpp -fopenmp
[me@my_cluster trial_openmp]$ qrsh -pe orte_pe 8
[me@compute-0-5 trial_openmp]$ ./a.out 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
```

The code did not get parallelized, if I check g++ version, I think openmp is properly installed:

```
[me@my_cluster trial_openmp]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/share/apps/gcc-4.8.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/share/apps/gcc-4.8.0 --with-gmp=/share/apps/gmp-5.1.1 --with-mpfr=/share/apps/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/share/apps/mpc-1.0.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.0 (GCC)
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Try getting each thread to print its own thread ID to be sure you havent got multiple threads. This is the more commonly used test - for example you might have multiple threads and they just happen to print in the right order...
Also try exporting how many threads you want before running the executable with export OMP_NUM_THREADS=x with x presumably being 8 for you

Comment: I am pretty sure that, they did not print in the right order by accident...

Comment: Yes its pretty unlikely, but possible. My point was simply that its worth using that method as a test program rather than simply printing numbers. Did you try the environment variable?

Comment: Oh, yea, the setting environment variables indeed resolves this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, that we worked out in the comments, was that wasabi123 needed to set the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable, if undefined only 1 thread per CPU is used.

`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=X`

Where x is the number of threads you want.